# Limiting distributions of random walks on torus, Klein bottle, cylinder and Mobius

Tags: probability-distributions, random-walk

I am looking into limiting distributions (LD) of random walks on some 2D surfaces. In particular, I am interested in the LD of a random walk on a torus, Klein bottle, cylinder and Mobius strip, but I can't seem to find much on this online. I would assume that the LD of the torus is uniform as the torus is $S^1 \times S^1$ and the the LD of the random walk on the circle is uniform. Is this correct? I am not sure what to expect for the other surfaces.

I was wondering if anyone knows any good references on the LD's of random walks on these surfaces?

Many thanks!

Comment: What sort of random walks are you considering here? Discrete-time, continuous time? What kind of steps?

Comment: I am interested in discrete-time random walks that step 1 step to the left or right based on the outcome of tossing a (fair) coin.

Comment: What do "1 step" or "left" or "right" mean on a surface?

Comment: Oh sorry, that wasn't very well explained on my part. At every time step, I toss two coins, one dictates the x-direction the walker walks in (i.e. left or right), and the other coin dictates the y-direction the walker walks in (i.e. up or down). I hope that's clearer!